# How to output MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, prepared-statement

I'm testing this code

```
$query = "SELECT * from `items` where category_id=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->query($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $category_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row['name'], $row['code']);
}
```

Is there any easier way to output whole table to HTML markup?

Comment: Dont think so man, you gotto go through the resultset and print each result, so this seems to he the shortest code. And its very simple too

Comment: A prepared statement seems like overkill here, as you're not passing any parameters into the query.  Is this actual code or a simplification for SO?

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon you can separate HTML output from SQL code. it would be indeed easier way.

Comment: Hey col, i wouldn't say its easier(what the question asked) to separate HTML from SQL. Though its better coding practice, and the code will be simpler looking. But its not "easier" to do than to just read the dbase and print the data out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet can match your requirements..but i'm not sure whether this is easier way or not..Hope this will help.

**For the php,**

```
$pricequery="SELECT price FROM technoxchange";
$result=mysql_query($pricequery);

while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $prices [] = $row['price'];
}

echo json_encode( array( 'prices' => $prices ) );
```

**For the js,**

```
var p;
$.get("getTechnoXchange.php", function(data){
    p = data.prices;
});

$('#priceUnicus').html( p[0] ); 
$('#priceHire').html( p[1] ); 
$('#priceMonsterArena').html( p[2] );
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any easier way to output whole table to HTML markup?

Sure.
Learn to use **templates**.

Just separate your prepared statements from output.
To do so, at first collect your data into array:

```
/* fetch values */
$data = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

and then start output with whatever HTML markup you like (preferably by means of including a separate template file:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="?id=<?= htmlspecialchars($row['id']) ?>">
        <?= htmlspecialchars($row['name']) ?>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```